# How to POST requests in Django with JS?

Tags: javascript, json, django, django-views, django-templates

I'm trying to add products in my basket without refreshing the page and i have

urls:

```
app_name = 'basket'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.BasketView.as_view(), name='summary'),
    path('/add', views.BasketView.post, name='basket_add'),
]
```

views:

```
class BasketView(generic.list.ListView):
    template_name = 'basket/basket.html'
    model = Category

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = request.POST
        print(data)
        return 'something'
```

html (+JS):

```
...
<button onclick="basket_add(this)" id="{{ item.id }}"></button>
...
<script>

  function send_productId(id){
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('POST', '{% url 'basket:basket_add' %}', true);
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
    const data = {
      id: id,
      csrfmiddlewaretoken:'{{ csrf_token }}',
      action: "POST",
    };
    request.send(data);
  };

  function basket_add(obj){
    send_productId(obj.id);
  };

</script>
```

after pressing the button i get this error

> Forbidden (CSRF token missing.): /basket/add

So how can i at least print data correctly or do i need to do it the other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution to your error. You can add `csrf_exempt` to your `post` method. This will allow you to submit the form without `csrf token`.

```py
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator

@method_decorator(csrf_exempt, name='dispatch')
class BasketView(generic.list.ListView):
    template_name = "basket/basket.html"
    model = Category

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = request.POST
        print(data)
        return "something"
```

PS: Inherit from `CreateView` or just from `View` class if you are using it to just create a new object. And in `urls.py` use your path something like this

```py
path("/add", BasketCreateView.as_view(), name='basket_add')
```

instead of your current path.
And have a look at [javascript fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)  to make server calls. It will make your life much easier.